# How does LiveAgent automatically links New Records created?

Tags: liveagent

Can somebody throw details on how a new Account created during a LiveAgent session is automatically linked with the LiveChat Transcript.

In the first screenshot, Agent starts conversation with a user and creates a new Account during the chat session.

[image: Created new Account 'kkkk' during chat session]

After the chat session ended, When I go to chat transcript, I can see that the Account created during the chat session is linked automatically, without agent having to do anything special.

[image: After the chat ended, Acc 'kkkk' is linked with the chat transcript]

Any clues on how it is being done?

Answer (score 1):

You go in the Salesforce Setup Menu under Built/Create/Apps.
Edit the Live Agent app as showed in the screenshot.
[image]
Does that answer your question?